# TotalRequests Limit exceeded error using force.com IDE

Tags: force.com, ide, governorlimits

We have a trial org and we currently have 7 developers working on the org. Currently all our developers are getting an error which is TotalRequests Limit exceeded if we use the force.com Ide. Do you guys know why this is happening and what can we do to fix it please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably because you ran out of API calls you can do in a day, every time you commit, save, run a test, fetch data, ... using the Force.com IDE / Eclipse you use an API call.
We had 2 developers hitting that limit in a day so you can image, with 7 people working on it, you'll get to that limit quite quickly.

You can view your current status in Setup -> System Overview
[image]

If it is for development and/or temporary use cases, salesforce will surely up your limits if you just submit a support case via either the partner portal, or contact your Account Manager

Comment: If this is the case, I would bet that Salesforce can probably help you out and increase your limit if you put in a case - https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000IFTOEA4

Comment: Salesforce is pretty flexible on this limit for short term needs, definitely loop them in if you're running into this