# 5000 request per 24 hour limit in development workarounds?

Tags: visualforce, force.com, ide

Our developers seem to be running into this limit every day by just using force.com IDE and doing SOQL calls to do development.

Any suggested work-arounds? Right now a couple developers have 2 developer sandboxes they are keeping up and switching between the two which is a huge pain.

Comment: Similar question here. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9463/totalrequests-limit-exceeded-error-using-force-com-ide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sign up for the ISVforce partner program. Becoming a partner comes without any strings attached. Therein, you get `Parner Development Environments`, than the usual `Delvelopment Environments`.

Once you generate one for yourself, do it for the team too. The limitations are much much lower. 10K API calls per 24 hour rolling window, for a start. Also, the number of users, sandboxes is higher. The bandwidth cap is higher. The storage limit is a good 250MB.