# Public site error "API_CURRENTLY_DISABLED"

Tags: force.com-sites, ajax-toolkit, guest-user

I'm getting a API_CURRENTLY_DISABLED error when I'm trying to call the ajax api (sforce.connection.create) from my public page.
In my site's public access settings I see the the 'API Enabled' option is checked.
Any ideas why I cannot call the ajax api?

Comment: Are you using a `Developer Edition` account or a trail `Professional/Enterprise/Ultimate Edition`?

Comment: I'm using an EE production/sandbox orgs

Comment: were you able to solve this ?

Comment: Does the account/profile your testing with have the API enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public API isn't available for the guest user. It's explicitly blocked.

Comment: So what is the point of having the 'API Enabled' checkbox in the Public Access settings?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Neither do `Trial Enterprise and Ultimate Editions` have API support, nor does Salesforce activate it on request.

Getting to a work-around, if you want to test the API, go for a `Developer Edition` account. Therein you can create multiple CRM users, manage `Accounts` and `Contacts` etc. But do note that the DE comes with certain restrictions that can be easily bypassed. [This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/14900/3428) will guide you into it.